# How get sum of a case?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my my case:

```
$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT 
  tablesite.name,
  tablesite.family,
  tablesite.phone_number,
  job_list.job_name,
  relation.comments,
SUM(CASE WHEN action.vote ='perfect' AND action.customer_comment ='' THEN 2
  WHEN action.vote ='nice' AND action.customer_comment ='' THEN 1
  WHEN action.vote ='not bad' AND action.customer_comment ='' THEN 0
  WHEN action.vote ='bad' AND action.customer_comment ='' THEN -1
  WHEN action.vote !='' AND action.moderator_view ='negative' THEN -1 
  WHEN action.vote !='' AND action.moderator_view ='positve' THEN 1
  WHEN action.vote !='' AND action.moderator_view ='no change' THEN 0 ELSE 0
END) positive
FROM tablesite
INNER JOIN relation
  on tablesite.id_user=relation.user_id
INNER JOIN job_list
  on relation.job_id=job_list.job_id 
left JOIN action
ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id
WHERE job_name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'
   OR name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'
   OR family LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'
group by name,family,job_name,phone_number", $con);
```

I want sum of chosen fields, example:

> vote=not bad, customer_comment='' ==> 0 point
>
> vote=bad, customer_comment='' ==> -1 point
>
> vote!="", moderator_view= negative ==> -1 point

Total should be -2

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  no summing just showed me one of chosen points. vote=nice , customer_comment='' ==> 1 point

vote=bad , customer_comment='' ==> -1 point. give me -1

Comment: are you using `GROUP BY` in your query? without that, it's not going to sum anything.

Comment: @Kryten i have put whole my code when i put positive in group by, give me error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Perhaps your sum contains null values which need to be coalesced to 0 or the result will be null.  If you eliminate the sums, do you get all the expected values for the case statement?

Comment: @xQbert i thing kryten idea is true about group by, but when i put positive in group by, i give a error

Comment: i hope your not using this in production, SQL-injection is real here...

Comment: @YoramdeLangen no its just student test

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a one to one relationship between `tablesite` and `relation` or between `relation` and `job_list` then this query will return unexpected results since you are retrieving `relation.comments` without adding it to your `GROUP BY` clause.

Remove `relation.comments` from the `SELECT` to get the correct sum.